# Saida de JSON alinhado em Python

Tags: python, json

Tenho o seguinte Json para ser tratado em python:

```
{
   "lojas": {
      "todas":[
         {
            "CodigoLoja": "001",
            "produtos":[
               {
                  "CodigoProduto": "001AAAAAAA",
                  "dataFabricacao": "11/11/2019",
                  "preco": "300,00"
               },
               {
                  "CodigoProduto": "001BBBBBBB",
                  "dataFabricacao": "2020-11-11",
                  "preco": "400,00"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "codigoLoja": "002",
            "produtos":[
               {
                  "CodigoProduto": "002AAAAAAA",
                  "dataFabricacao": "11/11/2018",
                  "preco": "500,00"
               },
               {
                  "CodigoProduto": "002BBBBBBB",
                  "dataFabricacao": "2017-11-11",
                  "preco": "600,00"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

A saída formatada que eu busco é:

```
codigoLoja      codigoProduto dataFabricacao      preco
001             001AAAAAAA    2019-11-11          300,00
001             001BBBBBBB    2020-11-11          400,00
002             002AAAAAAA    2018-11-11          500,00
002             002BBBBBBB    2017-11-11          600,00
```

Estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```
for each in data['lojas']['todas']:
    for produtos in each['produtos']:
        print(each['codigoLoja']+produtos['codigoProduto']+produtos['dataFabricacao']+produtos['preco'])
```

Isso até funciona, mas gostaria de saber se existe uma forma melhor de implementar, sem tem que definir o nome dos campos, pois caso inclua um novo campo em produtos (por exemplo, "descricao do produto"), não ter a necessidade de ficar alterando o código.

Comment: Tente um implementação em pandas. A solução será mais simples e possivelmente vc conseguirá automatizar para qualquer entrada dos nomes das chaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo seu exemplo, entendo que a estrutura JSON foi convertida para uma estrutura de dicionário.

Faça um loop dentro do produto.

```
for each in data['lojas']['todas']:
    for produto in each['produtos']:
        linha = each['codigoLoja']
        for chave, valor in produto.items():
            linha += valor
        print(linha)
```

Perceba que `linha += valor` colocará todos os valores "colados" como o exemplo abaixo:

```
001001AAAAAAA2019-11-11300,00
```

Para acertar isso, sugiro olhar os métodos `.ljust()`, `.rjust()`

O loop ficaria conforme abaixo:

```
linha = each['codigoLoja'].ljust(20)
for chave, valor in produto.items():
    linha += valor.rjust(20)
```

Todavia esta solução manteria um valor fixo de 20 posições para cada campo. Deixando conforme abaixo, por exemplo:

```
001                 001AAAAAAA          2019-11-11          300,00
```

Espero que ajude.